# Virtual Protect & PAGE_GUARD

Tags: c#, winapi

I relatively new to the win32 API, and I'm attempting to set the 'PAGE_GUARD' attribute on a processes' PE Header. However, this seems to fail every time that I try. I've looked into the documentation for 'VirtualProtectEx', and from what I see I have everything set up correctly. I have the first parameter(the HANDLE) set to the process I started's HANDLE, I have the lpAddress set the the process that I started's BaseAddress, I have the size set to 4096 which I am fairly sure is the header size for an x86 PE, I have the new protection set to '0x100' or '256u', which is PAGE_GUARD, and the old protection is 0.

Why doesn't this work?

```
namespace VirtualProtectTest
{
class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool VirtualProtectEx( IntPtr hProcess, uint dwAddress, int nSize, uint flNewProtect, out uint lpflOldProtect);


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process p = Process.Start("app.exe");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (VirtualProtectEx(p.Handle, (uint)p.MainModule.BaseAddress, 4096, 0x100, out uint a))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success!");
        }

        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fail!");
            p.Kill();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use only `PAGE_GUARD` (0x100) flag as protection is not valid - from [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566416(v=vs.85).aspx)

> This flag is a page protection modifier, **valid only when used with
>   one of the page protection flags other than PAGE_NOACCESS**.

so you need combine `PAGE_GUARD` with some other flags (except `PAGE_NOACCESS`). better of all first query for current page protection with `VirtualQueryEx` .code must be like this

```
HANDLE hProcess = NtCurrentProcess();
PVOID Address = &__ImageBase;
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
BOOL fOk;
if (fOk = (VirtualQueryEx(hProcess, Address, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)) == sizeof(mbi)))
{
    ULONG op;
    if (!(mbi.Protect & (PAGE_GUARD|PAGE_NOACCESS)))
    {
        fOk = VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, Address, PAGE_SIZE, PAGE_GUARD|mbi.Protect, &op);
    }
}
if (!fOk)
{
    GetLastError();
}
```

Comment: My question was in C#, but I'll take it. I have a question, though. How exactly do I tell if it worked properly?

Comment: Well ... at first glance, the most likely outcome is that the child process will crash.  So if that happens, the call probably worked.

Comment: Yup, that did it. Is there anyway to prevent the crash when another program tries to access the memory?

Comment: @HarryJohnston this "not work" exactly because use only `PAGE_GUARD` not valid. this flag must be combined with some another page protection flag, except `PAGE_NOACCESS`

Comment: RbMm, yes, I understand that.  I was responding to Richard's question about how he could tell that the change actually took effect.  Richard, I suppose if you attach to the child process as a debugger you would be able to intercept the guard page exception.  But what are you actually trying to achieve?